# Is my 7 seven segment Common Anode or Common Cathode

Tags: integrated-circuit, 7segmentdisplay

I am making a stopwatch, i bought a common cathode 7 segment and i installed resistors gave ground(-ve wire of battery) to pin 3 and positive to each segments including DP but i didnt glow, after that i gave ground to segments and red wire(+ve) to third pin and it started to glow so i am now confuse weather my 7-Segment is common cathode or common anode? Also if it is common anode then can i use IC 4033 (Decade Counter) with it? (As i saw some where that i need to use different decade counter with it)

Comment: Assuming pin 3 is the common... it sounds like common anode.

Comment: @Trevor yes pin 3 is common. Now what should i do? Which IC i need ?

Comment: Google for "4033 schematic" and look at the images tab: plenty of circuits. Note how Common Cathode displays can be controlled directly from the 4033 while the Common Anode is used with 7 transistors.

Comment: Since you didn't get what you paid for.. pin-out is also suspect.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks!! I will go buy Common Cathode 7-Segment cause i dont want that many components.

Comment: @Trevor what does that mean?

Comment: It means you ordered a common cathode display... you got something else. There is no guarantee what you got matches what you ordered in ANY way... including pin-out.

Comment: @Trevor well i tested each pin seperately so and noted a,b,c etc pins for it. Pin 3 was common because it didnt glow anything (this is how i need to test it right? If not then how to?)

Comment: I am sure you are right, and it sounds like you know what you are doing. It was just a comment. Just reminding you, you can't trust anything from the spec of what you think you bought.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks, I was just asking will buy common cathode one Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was common anode and it didnt work with 4033 IC, I replaced the common anode with common cathode segment and it started to work perfectly.